# How to remove blur effect in image generated by html-to-image

Tags: reactjs, npm, html-to-image

I'm using an npm dependency [html-to-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-image) in my react app.

When I try to generate the image, the result of the generated image has some blur effect.

can somebody explain to me how to increase the image quality or give me an alternative, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to correct the problem. just increase the pixelRatio option in the configuration of render and it will increase image quality